# highlight active page link in React/Gatsby

Tags: css, reactjs, hyperlink, gatsby

Not using React Router here, would like to keep it simple. I'm using Gatsby which has an `activeClassName` attribute with its `<Link>` system, however, I think it's not working because I'm using it on a main nav, then I have a subnav with categories.

The solution I came up for the subnav is a little function to see if you're in a directory:

```
  const activeStyle = {
    color: "green",
    background: "red",
  }
  function pathIncludes(word) {
    return window.location.href.includes(word) ? { activeStyle } : ""
  }
```

and then inside my return():

```
<ul>
    <li styles={pathIncludes('motion')}>
        <Link to="./motion">Motion</Link>
    </li>
    <li styles={pathIncludes('design')}>
        <Link to="./design">Design</Link>
    </li>
    <li styles={pathIncludes('illustration')}>
        <Link to="./illustration">Illustration</Link>
    </li>
</ul>
```

It *almost* works, rendered on the page I get `<li class="[object Object]">`

How can I pass it the jsx?

Or, is there a better way to do this, that doesn't involve installing extra dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem are the brackets `{}` around `activeStyle` in the line

`return window.location.href.includes(word) ? { activeStyle } : ""`

They act as destructuring `activeStyle` which is an object. But style expects an object. So

`return window.location.href.includes(word) ? activeStyle : ""` `

should work.

Comment: Thanks Michael, hmm thought that would for sure be it but I still get an [Object object]. puzzling.

Comment: Returning an empty string might also be a problem. Instead returning an empty object should do the trick `return window.location.href.includes(word) ? activeStyle : {}`
I also just saw that you're using `<li styles...` I'm not familiar with the `styles` attribute. Are you sure you don't mean `style`?

Comment: I couldnt get that to work either, very strange! Thanks though!

Comment: just in case anyone is having an issue with Gatsby Link-- I found the problem I had was because I was doing `<Link activeClassName={navStyles.active} to="./contact">` instead of `<Link activeClassName={navStyles.active} to="/contact">`. no period in the address.

Comment: you know what I tried your solution a few days later and it worked. Thanks Michael!

Answer (score 3):

I tried the accepted reply, it works fine for URLs having path tails (example.com/**about**) but doesn't work for home pages (example.com/).

I lurked a bit and found much more elegant solution which makes use of [native Gatsby's](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-link/#use-getprops-for-advanced-link-styling) `<Link>` `getProps` prop (*read [@reach/routes documentation](https://reach.tech/router/api/Link) for more*).

So, if we add a home page to your example (even if not, it still seems to be more appropriate way to style the active links), the solution will look like this:

```
function isActive( {isCurrent} ) {
    return isCurrent ? {className: "active"} : null
}

<ul>
  <li>
    <Link to="/" getProps={isActive}>Home</Link>
  </li>
  <li>
    <Link to="/design" getProps={isActive}>Design</Link>
  </li>
  <li>
    <Link to="/illustration" getProps={isActive}>Illustration</Link>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks!